# How to set the default urlpatterns for Django projects

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-urls

Whenever I start a Django project the url patterns are like this:

url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)

I am using venv and I install the latest version of Django so shouldn't the url patterns default to?:

path('admin/', admin.site.urls)

In the auto comments at the top of the urls.py file it seems to be referencing Django 1.11 even though I am using 3.03:

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/

Comment: It should have been just like you mentioned. Please verify the Django version within your environment.

Comment: Make sure you are creating the Django Project from an environment which already has Django 3.x

Comment: I pip install django before starting the project. When I run python console django.VERSION, I get (3,0,3, 'final',0)

Comment: It is tricky to tell now, but I'd want to be certain that it's python3 that is set as the version being used in the virtualenv, then afterward pip install django.